# Styling html table

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

```
  <table border="1" width="600" align="center">
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="right">date</td>
       </tr>

         <tr>
            <td width="10%">avatar</td> //cant balance those two proportionally 10 to 90
            <td  width="90%">message</td>
         </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                  <table border="1" width="600">
                    <tr>
                          <td width="48%"></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                            <td width="12%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Remove" style="width:60px"/> </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Quote" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Reply" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Rep" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

            </td>


        </tr>
    </table>
```

If you look above the proportions fo those cells dont work. I want one cell to be 10% and the other 90%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border="1" width="600" align="center">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="right">date</td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
        <td style="width:60px">avatar</td>
        <td style="width:540px">message</td>
     <tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
              <table border="1" width="600">
                <tr>
                      <td width="48%"></td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                        <td width="12%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Remove" style="width:60px"/> </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Quote" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Reply" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center"><input type="button" value="Rep" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

        </td>


    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When using percentages as values for the width attribute in td, web browsers will automatically resize your table according to available screen space defined in the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You miss tr on the first row.

```
<table border="1" width="600" align="center">
<tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="right">date</td>
</tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="10%" style="">avatar</td>
            <td  width="90%">message</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                  <table border="1" width="600">
                    <tr>
                          <td width="70%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><input type="button" value="Quote" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><input type="button" value="Reply" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                            <td width="10%" align="right"><input type="button" value="Rep" style="width:50px"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>

            </td>


        <tr>
    </table>
```